# Creating indices using means of variables in R

Tags: r, indexing

I am trying to create an index of a set of variables by taken the mean of the selected variables using the following code:

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  # Standardize each component/measure
  mutate(
    std_var1 = standardize(var1, Z),
    std_var2 = standardize(var2, Z),
    std_var3 = standardize(var3, Z),
    std_var4 = standardize(var4, Z)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(std_var1,
                std_var2,
                std_var3,
                std_var4) %>%
  # Average all z scores for an individual
  mutate(index = pmap_dbl(., ~ mean(c(...), na.rm = T))) %>%
  cbind(data, .) %>% unnest() %>%
```

I also use the [idx_mean package](https://rdrr.io/github/graemeblair/stdidx/src/R/idx_mean.R) that takes the following syntax:

```
mutate(data, idx_var = idx_mean(std_var1, std_var2, std_var3, std_var4))
```

and obtain similar but not exactly the same index values (not just a matter of rounding).

Is there one approach that seems more accurate here?

The 4th and 5th columns display index values created by the idx function (4th column) and the other approach (5th column.)
[image]

Comment: What package is `standardize` from?

Comment: And if you want us to dig in to inconsistencies, you should probably share a small bit of example data that demonstrates these inconsistencies.

Comment: ```Standardize``` is a function I wrote to compute the z-score of the variables used to create the indices.

Comment: ```standardize = function(x, Z){(x - mean(x[Z==0], na.rm = TRUE))/sd(x[Z==0], na.rm = TRUE)}
```

Comment: Minor FYI, you might be interested in `dplyr::across`, which lets you do, e.g., `mutate(across(var1:var4, standardize, Z, .names = "std_{.col}"))` instead of writing out the same `standardize` line for each column.

Comment: Glancing at the code for `idx_mean`, it has a `fill_na` option that defaults to TRUE and is described as "to fill missing values from any variable with linear predictions from all of the other variables." My guess is that is your source of inconsistency. Try setting `fill_na = FALSE` in the `idx_mean()` and see if there is still inconsistency.

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much.

Comment: Btw. The `scale` function of base R does exactly what you do with your standardize function.